# Depictions of aliens in Old Man's War

Tags: aliens, old-mans-war, john-scalzi

For the Old Man's War series are there any sanctioned, visual depictions of what the various aliens species look like?  For most of the aliens I can form a mental picture in my head from their descriptions, but for some species (particularly the Obin) I am totally at a loss to how they may actually look.

Comment: There's some concept art here for a failed pilot; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ph74gkuBDkM

Comment: Related: [Does Scalzi describe what the Rraey look like?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/36796/98028)

Comment: @Valorum From skimming that video I thought the aliens presented were passed off as "something he prepared for an earlier project".  But aside from that I hated his OMW uniform and ship designs - not keeping on the spirit of the books at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the Obin's on the Subterranean Press Illustrated edition of Zoe's Tale: 
https://vincentchongart.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/zoes-tale-cover/
[image: Zoe's Tale cover featuring Zoe and her Obin protectors]

Also another picture in the gallery of Vincent Chong:
www.vincentchong-art.co.uk/2009 the obin.html

Fuglies: www.vincentchong-art.co.uk/2009 fuglies.html
[image: Fuglies from book The Last Colony]

Comment: Not like anything I had pictured in my mind!

Comment: Me neither at the time. :D These two actually remind me on Yarael Poof the long necked Jedi Master from The Phantom Menace.